# Add UIImageView to UINavigation bar not in a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I'm presenting a view controller modally that contains a navigation bar. This view controller is not embedded in a navigation controller. I don't have `titleView` available or other things from the navigation controller to use for this. Also interface builder does not seem to allow me to just drag and drop a `UIImageView` onto a `UINavigationBar` Is there an easy way to add this and center the imageview in the middle of the UINavigationBar?

Comment: Try to add a UIView and put the imageView on this UIView

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to present controller with navigation controller.

```
YourViewController *viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] viewController];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:TRUE completion:^{  }];
```

And then in `YourViewController.m` in `viewDidLoad()` :

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [self setImageInTitleOfbar:@"imagename.png"];
```

Implement this method,

```
- (UIView *)setImageInTitleOfbar:(NSString *)imageName
{
    UIImageView *imgLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 32)];
    imgLogo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    return imgLogo;

    /*UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -5, 160, 35)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    imgLogo.frame = CGRectMake(3, 0, view.frame.size.width-6, view.frame.size.height);
    [view addSubview:imgLogo];
    return view;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@zig10,

**here is the solution to set uiimageview in UINavigation Bar in TitleView**.

```
        self.navigationItem.titleView=nil;
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
        img.backgroundColor=ColorClear;
        img.tag=101010;
        self.navigationItem.titleView = img;
```

**i have also set UITextField in UiNavigation Bar using below code, may be helpful to you**

```
 tfNavTitle = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
        tfNavTitle.backgroundColor=ColorClear;
        tfNavTitle.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
        tfNavTitle.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        tfNavTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19];
        tfNavTitle.textColor = ColorWhite;
        tfNavTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        tfNavTitle.delegate=self;
        tfNavTitle.tag=101010;
        [tfNavTitle becomeFirstResponder];

        tfNavTitle.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Search" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: ColorWhite}];

        //Set Animation
        [tfNavTitle.layer addAnimation:[ApplicationDelegate AnimateFromRight] forKey:nil];

        self.navigationItem.titleView = tfNavTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get `titleView` in `Navigation Bar` because you haven't add `Navigation Item` to `Navigation Bar`

1. Add `Navigation Bar`
2. Add `Navigation Item` to `Navigation Bar`
3. create `IBOutlet` of `Navigation Item`
4. set `UIImageView` to `navigationItem`

**Example**

```
@IBOutlet var navitaionBarItem: UINavigationItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navitaionBarItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "sample.png"))
}
```